# How to test python database interacting functions

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, flask, sqlalchemy

I have some function in my python file course.py which is in proj/com/api/course 
folder. These function interact with database.

I am using flask, sqlalchemy .

course.py

```
def create(**kwargs):
            user = User()
            session = Session()
            user.name = kwargs['name']
            user.email = kwargs['email']
            session.add(user)
            session.commit()
            session.close()
            return user
def get_data_by_id(user_id):
        session = Session()
        user = session.query(User).filter(User.id==user_id).first()
        session.close()
        return user
```

My question is where should I create testing module and how set connections with data base to test functions?

Comment: This is a bit broad and there are a multitude of ways to go about this.  First off, look into python unittest frameworks.  There is the built in unittest as well as opensource projects like nose and pytest.  As far as setting the connections, I would recommend injection, pass the session variable as an argument to your functions.  That way you can simply inject the session relevant to your tests.